# Multiplying all integers in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, math

I need to multiply all integers inside a given array by -1. I dont see where I'm making a mistake, but here is my code so far:

```
public static int[] InvertValues(int[] input)
{
int x = -1;
  foreach(int y in input)
   { 
    x *= y;
  }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? multiply each element in the array by -1 (flip sign?) ?? because what you do is multiply each element with each other - and then returning the original input back since you dont  do anything with your ```x``` variable.

Comment: `x *= y;` is equivalent to `x = x * y;` (if you didn't know)

Comment: im trying to multiply each by -1 (flip sign), yes. as you guys can probably tell, im pretty new to this. when i add a Console.WriteLine, the array comes back correctly in all places except at index 0.

Comment: in that case you should use a ```for``` loop so you can write back your result into the input array.

Answer (score 2):

This is one solution based on the author's initial attempt:

That will multiply each single element with -1.

What your mistake was is that you need to access each individual element of the array and write it back via an index. To do that you should better use a `for` loop.

Then you access the original value in your input array, multiply it with -1 and write it back into, overwriting the original value in the input array.

```cs
public static int[] InvertValues(int[] input)
{

  for(int index = 0; index<input.Length;index++)
  { 
    input[index] = input[index] * -1;
  }
  
  return input;
}
```

I would go the next step and not change the original input array and return a copy instead:

```cs
public static int[] InvertValues(int[] input)
{
  int[] results = new int[input.Length]

  for(int index = 0; index<input.Length;index++)
  { 
    results [index] = -input[index]; //this flips the sign of the number, no need to do * -1
  }
  
  return results;
}
```

A better and shorter alternative :)

```
using System.Linq; //need to be added

//...

public static int[] InvertValues(int[] input)
{
  return input.Select(x=> -x).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thank you! i had originally tried creating a new array and it was bringing an error for converting int to int[], i hadnt thought to just do the original array * -1.

Comment: @John, feel free to submit your edit again.

Comment: @d3lliott there are different ways to solve it, in fact i probably would not change the original array and return a copy with the results.

Comment: im excited to get to really know Linq, so many of the shorter, cleaners answers i see are using the Linq directory. ive just started using it for some things.

Comment: @d3lliott before using LINQ or any other "complex" library of the .NET framework you should really focus on getting the basics down.

Comment: thats why ive tried using what im more learning, rather than some of the Linq shortcuts i find on this site. Stack overflow has been a great rescourse, but copy pasting doesnt help me learn, however easy it might be. once i get there, id love to write one liners that can accomplish what now takes me over 10.

Comment: `A better and shorter alternative :)` Debatable whether it is better. It allocates a new array which may be better, or not better, depending on what the OP wants. It will definitely use more memory.

Comment: @mjwills that is exactly why! You shouldn't change the input array in your method, it would be unexpected behavior especially if your method signature actually returns an array.

Comment: @Tomek Again, it depends on what the expectation is. _Generally_ preferable - probably.

Comment: I agree with @mjwills. I would make it `void`. The LINQ version is going to allocate a bunch of arrays, as the `Select` is masking the size. For an immutable version, I would stick with the middle option you have

Comment: @Charlieface exactly, with ```void``` as return type you can assume it will change the input array. Why clone when using void, then you need to also pass in as ```ref``` ... that definitely makes it clear it will change the original input :-D

Comment: No sorry, I meant for the immutable version, clone and return, but use the same algorithm, not LINQ